# Get children element height in separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the child elements of each div and then set the height of each div according to their respective total child elements height.

I tried to find a similar question but can't find what I wanted. I know I needed an .each function but I can't get it to work.

Below is my code :

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>content</h1>
      <a href="#">content</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>very long contents</h1>
      <p>content</p>
      <a href="#">content</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>super uber ultra long contents</h1>
      <p>content</p>
      <a href="#">content</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
        $("ul li div").each(function(){
            var div_ht = 0;
            $("ul li div").children().each(function() {
                div_ht += $(this).outerHeight(true);
            });
            $("ul li div").height(div_ht);
        });
    });
```

What I want to achieve is let's say the 1st div's child element's total height is 100px, then it will set the 1st div to 100px height. If the 2nd div's child element's total height is 300px, then it will set the 2nd div to 300px height.

Comment: If I am correct, you are trying to get the average height for each div child elements?

Comment: Hi Fil, thanks for your help but I have already solved my issue with gurvinder's help. I am not getting the average height for each div child elements. I am actually wanting to set each div's height according to their own child elements' height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @gurvinder372 answer, you might as well use a single query:

```
$("ul li div").each( function() {
  var divHeight = 0;
  $(this).children().each( function() {
    divHeight += $(this).height();
  });
  $(this).height(divHeight);
})
```

as you want to do the job for each `ul li div` elements.
It is important to note that, inside a each/function statement:

- `this` points to the HTML element (see the reference documentation)
- `$(this)` points to the JQuery element constructed from the HTML element (thus giving you all the flexibility of the JQuery library)

**edit**
The function `find` performs a new *selection* starting from the selection it is called from.

Perform a selection from the root on "ul li" elements then do a subselection on each element:

```
$("ul li").find("div");
```

Perform a selection frmo the root on `ul li div` elements => This should be more efficient, use it if you don't plan to do any job on the `ul li` level:

```
$("ul li div");
```

This is equivalent to `$("").find("ul li div")`;

Comment: Thanks for the simplified version! It's kind of wierd that I did use $("ul li div").each(); function before, but it returned me all the height of the child elements in 3 divs. But now it's working perfectly fine. @.@

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){ //this line changed, iterating individual li's div rather than whole bunch
        var div_ht = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function() { //observe change in this line too
            div_ht += $(this).outerHeight(true);
        });
        $(this).height(div_ht); //observe change in this line too
    });
});
```

Also, if you simply want to set the height of div as the sum on their children height, then simply set the height of those `div` to `auto`

```
$("ul li div").css("height", "auto");
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot! I've been trying 2 days and still can't achieve it. I can't use height auto because my div is using position absolute and I needed to make it display middle. So the key thing is to use .find. It's kind of confusing to me though, the difference between using .find and not using it.